# WPF item control grid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to make grid that would contain some number of buttons (1,4,8).

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--<Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></Button>
    </Grid>-->
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TheList}" x:Name="MyGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="1">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Command="{Binding One}">1</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding Four}">4</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding Eight}">8</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
namespace WpfApplication9
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
/// 

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class ViewModelTest : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Button> theList;
        public ObservableCollection<Button> TheList
        {
            get { return theList; }
            set { theList = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("TheList"); }
        }
        public ViewModelTest()
        {
            One = new RelayCommand(() => OneButton());
            Four = new RelayCommand(() => FourButton());
            Eight = new RelayCommand(() => EightButton());



            //TheList.Clear();
            //for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            //{
            //    System.Windows.Controls.Button newBtn = new Button();
            //    newBtn.Content = i.ToString();
            //    newBtn.Name = "Button" + i.ToString();
            //    TheList.Add(newBtn);
            //}
        }
        public ICommand One { get; set; }
        public ICommand Four { get; set; }
        public ICommand Eight { get; set; }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
        public void OneButton()
        {
            TheList = new ObservableCollection<Button>();                
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                System.Windows.Controls.Button newBtn = new Button();
                newBtn.Content = i.ToString();
                newBtn.Name = "Button" + i.ToString();
                TheList.Add(newBtn);
            }
        }
        public void FourButton()
        {
            TheList = new ObservableCollection<Button>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                System.Windows.Controls.Button newBtn = new Button();
                newBtn.Content = i.ToString();
                newBtn.Name = "Button" + i.ToString();
                TheList.Add(newBtn);
            }

            //MyGrid.Children.Clear();
            //MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
            //MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear();
            //MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            //MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            //MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
            //MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
            //for (int row =0;row<MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count;row++)
            //{
            //    for (int column=0;column<MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count;column++)
            //    {
            //            System.Windows.Controls.Button newBtn = new Button();
            //            newBtn.Content = row.ToString() + column.ToString();
            //            newBtn.Name = "Button" + row.ToString()+column.ToString();
            //            newBtn.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty,column);
            //            newBtn.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, row);
            //            MyGrid.Children.Add(newBtn);
            //    }
            //}
        }
        public void EightButton()
        {
            TheList = new ObservableCollection<Button>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                System.Windows.Controls.Button newBtn = new Button();
                newBtn.Content = i.ToString();
                newBtn.Name = "Button" + i.ToString();
                TheList.Add(newBtn);
            }
            //MyGrid.Children.Clear();
            //MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
            //MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear();
            //MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            //MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            //MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            //MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            //MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
            //MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
            //for (int row = 0; row < MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; row++)
            //{
            //    for (int column = 0; column < MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; column++)
            //    {
            //        System.Windows.Controls.Button newBtn = new Button();
            //        newBtn.Content = row.ToString() + column.ToString();
            //        newBtn.Name = "Button" + row.ToString() + column.ToString();
            //        newBtn.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, column);
            //        newBtn.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, row);
            //        MyGrid.Children.Add(newBtn);
            //    }
            //}
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {

        DataContext = new ViewModelTest();
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```

But I have a problem with displaying. How can I create new columns and rows in itemcontrol dynamically in this case.

Comment: Do you need those buttons to exist for every item in the items control or something else? Maybe a sketch of what you want?

Comment: Yes i need those buttons exist for every time until switch another type 1 or 8.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, where to begin....
You've got a couple problems here.

1. TheList is an ObservableCollection, so there is no need for using 'NotifyPropertyChanged' in the TheList property.  And no need for the theList member variable.  Just use the following for your property:

   public ObservableCollection TheList { get; set; }
2. However, in your code behind, 'TheList' doesn't get initialized until one of your buttons is clicked.  Your XAML, therefore is binding to a null object, so pretty much not binding to anything, no matter what you change 'TheList' to after the binding, you're still bound to null.  To fix this, make sure to initialize TheList in your constructor before your InitializeComponents() call.  Change your constructor to the following:

   `public MainWindow()
    {
        TheList = new ObservableCollection<Button>(); 
        DataContext = new ViewModelTest();
        InitializeComponent();
    }`

Also, all the places where you are setting `TheList = new ObservableCollection<Button>()` just changes the pointer to something else, so the Binding gets broken again.  Instead of re-initializing TheList, just do `TheList.Clear();` and then add your buttons to TheList using `TheList.Add(newBtn);`

3. So, it looks like you have a bunch of RowDefinitions without heights, I'm guessing these are just place holders?  You could name your Grid something like `x:Name="MyInternalGrid"` and then when you're adding to `TheList`, do the same thing with adding rows to `MyInternalGrid`.  So when call `TheList.Clear();`  also clear your gridRows by calling `MyInternalGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear();`.  Then, whenever you call `TheList.Add(newBtn);`, add another row to your grid with `MyInternalGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition{Height=20});`.  When you do that, make sure to assign the correct row to your newBtn.  `Grid.SetRow(newBtn, MyInternalGrid.RowDefinitions.Count);` before adding the `newBtn` to `TheList`.  Here's what I mean, change your methods to mimic the refactored `EightButton()` method below:

   `public void EightButton()
   {
       TheList.Clear();
       MyInternalGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear();
       for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
       {
           Button newBtn = new Button();
           newBtn.Content = i.ToString();
           newBtn.Name = "Button" + i.ToString();
           Grid.SetRow(newBtn, MyInternalGrid.RowDefinitions.Count);

           MyInternalGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition{Height=20});
           TheList.Add(newBtn);
       }
   }`

Or, you might just want to not worry about all the grid rows and put a `<StackPanel>` inside your `<Grid>` and add all the buttons to that `<StackPanel>` dynamically.  Just clear the stack panel first, `MyStackPanel.Children.Clear();`  and then in the loop add the new button like this `MyStackPanel.Children.Add(newBtn);`

Home some of this helps.